# Kotlin Select returns INT instead of Decimal

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, casting, integer, decimal

I am trying to get some decimal values of my SQLite database by using this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Tankstelle
           WHERE ((LOWER(Place) LIKE 'k%ln') OR (LOWER(Place) LIKE 'm%nchengladbach'))
           AND AbfrageZeitpunkt BETWEEN '2021-10-11'
           AND '2021-10-13'
           AND Distance <= 0.8
           ;
```

Inside my db software (DBeaver) this statements returns the correct values. But if I use this statement inside a while(result.next()) method in Kotlin where I grab the values for each row it returns the INT values of the rows that are decimals in the db. I am getting the values by using:

```
val diesel = result.getDouble("Diesel)
```

I already tried it with getFloat or getBigDecimal and long and so on but it doesn't change.

I also tried it by removing the * from the select statement and writing alls the columns down that I want and using the CAST(Diesel AS FLOAT) method. Nothing...

The returns are rounded down to the next lower Int.

Thank you already!

Comment: What does your data look like? Using `,` or `.` as decimal separator?

Comment: Inside my database? It's seperated by a comma

Comment: Ok, because of your answere I changed it to getString instead of getDouble and it worked. It's maybe not the best soloution but the data is correct now so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`getDouble()` expects to have `.` as decimal separator. If you use `,` comma as decimal separator the conversion doesn't work.

Prefer to have data in your database in "engineering" format with `.` decimal separator. Convert to a presentation format appropriate for your locale in your code then.

As a workaround, you can get the value e.g. as a string instead.

Comment: Yea I didn't thought about that. My bad but I changed it to getString() now and it worked. Thank you!